# Jquery ajax error callback is executed even though the response http status is 200

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have written simple ajax code, in success callback I have written an alert but it does not work.

The code is:

```
$(".change_forex_transaction_status").click(function(){
  $("#insufficient_funds").css("display","none");
  var id = $(this).attr('data-transaction_id');
  //var ttype = $(this).attr('data-ttype');
  if (confirm("Are you sure you want to mark this transaction as complete?")) {
    $(this).unbind("click");
    $.ajax({
      url:"<?php echo Yii::app()->getBaseUrl(true);?>/customer/changeForexTransactionStatus",
      type:"POST",
      dataType: "json",
      //data:{id:id,tidentify:2,ttype:ttype},
      data:{id:id,tidentify:2},
      success:function(res){
        if(res == "unauthorized"){
          alert("You Are not authorize to perform this action.");

        }else{
        if(res == "success"){
          location.reload();
        } else if(res == "insufficient_fund"){
          alert('Insufficient Fees');
          $("#insufficient_funds").css("display","block");
        } else if(res == 'invalid_fee_account'){
          alert('Invalid Merchant Fees Account');
        }
      }
      },
      error:function(t) {
        console.log(t);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Even though the response http status code is 200, it goes into error callback whereas it should have gone in success callback and opened an alert box.

Can anyone please help on this.

Comment: so .... what error is it showing? and what else is showing in the console, any other errors or messages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are expecting json back not text so change the ajax dataType to text

```
 dataType: "text",
```

Comment: Also, you can add that, if the OP wants to send `JSON`, he have to add a `contentType: "application/json"`.

Comment: @ADreNaLiNe-DJ depends on the server side implementation

Comment: You're right, but often, people are misunderstanding `contentType` and `dataType`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `JSON.stringify` to post data on server, and when you post data to server in json so use content type `"application/json"`. Now if you expect data in json from server then use `dataType: "json"`. If data from server is html then you can use  `dataType: "html"` or it is text then you can use `dataType: "text"`.

```
data: JSON.stringify({ id: id, tidentify: 2 }),
contentType: "application/json",
dataType: "json"
```